# Importing BIP-84 keys to Bitcoin Core or similar?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets, bech32-address

I generated a mnemonic and keys using the BIP-84 scheme and sent funds to a public address from that scheme over time. I have been using this as a paper wallet, unattached to any wallet software.

I can see the amounts fine on a block explorer, but when I attempted to import the private key for that address on blockchain.com their import scheme appears to use BIP-44, so it doesn't import the correct bech32 / BIP84 public address.

What are my options for getting a transaction signed using this BIP84 scheme, to send some funds?

I am comfortable with command line or programmatically creating transactions in js or another language, but I'm wondering is it possible to import a BIP-84 private key for easy signing on Bitcoin Core? Or other software that people may know of?

I have both the mnemonic / root keys / private keys, so that's no issue.

Comment: So I am not sure if this is an "authoritative" answer, but I eventually found Electrum. It allows you to import BIP-84 private keys and I was able to send what I wanted. There are caveats about privacy and sweeping vs. importing, but Electrum was helpful.